# remember-chords not working in leadsheets package

Tags: music, leadsheets

So I'm trying to use the `leadsheets` package but am having trouble getting the `remember-chords` to work. I've looked at the documentation (http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/leadsheets/leadsheets_en.pdf p.24) and can not find my mistake.

I've tried inserting the chords manually (without using just the `^` shortcut) and it works, but inserts the chord above the text and in the text.

The error I get when running this code is `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{song}`
It then tries to solve the issue by inserting various characters at line 19 before failing.

Below is my example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{leadsheets}
\setleadsheets{align-chords={l}}
\begin{document}

\begin{song}[remember-chords]{title={Piano Man}, music={Billy Joel}}
    \begin{verse}
        It's ^{C}nine O' ^{G}clock on a ^*{F}Satur ^{C}day \\
        The ^{F}regular ^{C}crowd shuffles ^{D7}in ^{G} \\
        There's and ^{C}old man ^{G}sitting ^{F}next to ^{C}me \\
        Making ^{F}love to his ^{G}tonic and ^{C}gin ^{G}
    \end{verse}
    \begin{verse}
        He says, ^"Son, can you ^play me a ^*memo ^ry \\
        I'm ^not really ^sure how it ^goes ^ \\
        But it's ^sad and it's ^sweet and I ^knew it com ^plete \\
        When I ^wore a ^younger man's ^clothes." ^
    \end{verse}
\end{song}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remember-chords` has a problem if the replacement marker `^` is the last thing in a line. This is (at least for the time being) a known limitation. Just add an empty group after it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{leadsheets}
\setleadsheets{align-chords={l}}
\begin{document}

\begin{song}[remember-chords]{title={Piano Man}, music={Billy Joel}}
\begin{verse}
  It's ^{C}nine o'^{G}clock on a ^*{F}Satur ^{C}day \\
  The ^{F}regular ^{C}crowd shuffles ^{D7}in ^{G} \\
  There's and ^{C}old man ^{G}sitting ^{F}next to ^{C}me \\
  Making ^{F}love to his ^{G}tonic and ^{C}gin ^{G}
\end{verse}
\begin{verse}
  He says, ^``Son, can you ^play me a ^*memo ^ry \\
  I'm ^not really ^sure how it ^goes ^ {} \\ % <<<
  But it's ^sad and it's ^sweet and I ^knew it com^plete \\
  When I ^wore a ^younger man's ^clothes.'' ^ {} % <<<
\end{verse}
\end{song}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: BTW: I also replaced the incorrect `"..."` with the correct `\`\`...''`

Comment: Interesting. I assume that this is meant to be obvious in the "Caveat" section immediately preceeding "Remember Chords", but I find it far from obvious. Perhaps the documentation should be updated to make it explicit.

Comment: @FredHockney actually no, it really isn't that obvious. I'll add a note in the manual